# Is is possible to offset a constraint by the size of another view in iOS?

Tags: ios, autolayout, masonry-ios-osx

I am using masonry to programmatically setup constraints on views. Several times I have wanted to offset a constraint by a characteristic of another view. Is that possible?

For example, I'd like to do this:

```
[self.someView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.centerX.equalTo(self.mas_centerX).offset(self.otherView.mas_width);
}];
```

which of course doesn't compile because `offset` expects a number and not a constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `self.otherView.mas_width` in your offset, why not use `self.otherView.frame.size.width`? Use `height` instead of `width` if you want the height of the view. This is the correct way to get the width or height of a view.

Comment: The constraints are often set up before the views have sizes so I don't think constraining to frame.width would work. Also, if otherViews width changes the constraint would not update.